# HTML returning as text Laravel Controller

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to return HTML from Laravel controller, but it is returning as plan text:
Example: `<input type="checkbox" class="row-select" value="9">`

```
->addColumn('mass_delete', function ($row) {
    return  '<input type="checkbox" class="row-select" value="' . $row->id .'">' ;
})

->editColumn('installation_status', function ($row) { 
    return ($row->installation_status) ? "<span class='label bg-green'>Required</span>" :  "<span class='label bg-red'>Not Required</span>";
})
```

Comment: where it is showing?

Comment: Add `->rawColumns(['mass_delete', 'installation_status'])` to the end of line

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, you are probably using [Laravel Datatables](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master). If that's the case, in order to render HTML in the table itself, you need to use [rawColumns()](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/raw-columns) function:

```
->addColumn('mass_delete', function ($row) {
            return  '<input type="checkbox" class="row-select" value="' . $row->id .'">' ;
        })

->editColumn('installation_status', function ($row) {
                return ($row->installation_status) ? "<span class='label bg-green'>Required</span>" :  "<span class='label bg-red'>Not Required</span>";
        })
->rawColumns(['mass_delete', 'installation_status']);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Blade **{{ }}** statements are automatically sent through PHP's **htmlspecialchars** function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the **{!! !!}** syntax:

**ForExample**

**Cntroller.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $html = "<b>Hello</b>";

    return view('welcome', compact('html));
}
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
        {{ $html }}
        <br/>
        {!! $html !!}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Result**

```
<b>Hello</b>
Hello //but bold
```